# Naruto Hat Bug?

Tags: bug, winter-bash

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1074548/differentiating-a-constant-and-switching-order/1074558#1074558) of mine got accepted several minutes before it got the first upvote. Yet, I did not get the Naruto hat. Is this a bug? I suspect it's not since others have gotten this hat, yet according to the description, I should have gotten it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a bug as description of [Naruto](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/naruto) hat on Winter bash page says.

[image]

> *Post an accepted answer that receives no other votes for $12$ hours*

And according to your reputation history and statement in question your answer was up-voted within few minutes.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I saw the shortened description of this hat which said "accepted with no votes" and didn't see the longer description. I'll see if I can get this question deleted.

Comment: @AhaanS.Rungta No need to delete questions in such cases: if you overlooked something, chances are a few other people did too.